# Invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have this error come up, and I cannot fully see why is happening. I am trying to use a template function inside a base class as such:

*in .h file*

```
class CylindricalWave {
public:
    virtual ~CylindricalWave() {}
    virtual double intensity(double r, double z, double t) = 0;
    virtual std::complex<double> efield(double r, double z, double t) = 0;

    template<int Nr, int Nz>
    Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Nz, Nr> efield(Eigen::Matrix<double, Nz, Nr>& rs, Eigen::Matrix<double, Nz, Nr>& zs, double t);

    template<int Nr, int Nz>
    Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Nz, Nr> intensity(Eigen::Matrix<double, Nz, Nr>& rs, Eigen::Matrix<double, Nz, Nr>& zs, double t);
};
```

I define my template methods in the *.h file* as well:

```
template<int Nr, int Nz>
Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Nz, Nr> CylindricalWave::efield(Eigen::Matrix<double, Nz, Nr>& rs, Eigen::Matrix<double, Nz, Nr>& zs, double t) {
        Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Nz, Nr> output;
        for (size_t i = 0, size = rs.size(); i < size; i++)
        {
            
            double temporary_r = (*(rs.data() + i));
            double temporary_z = (*(zs.data() + i));

            *(output.data()+i) = this->efield(temporary_r, temporary_z, t); //here I call the virtual efield of Cylindrical Wave. I thought the compiler would understand that it has to call the child method that accepts doubles.

            
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Now I have a child class called `GaussianBeam` where I override the efield method:

```
class GaussianBeam : public CylindricalWave {
    public:

        
        virtual std::complex<double> efield(double r, double z, double t); //this is the define this virtual method.


        virtual double intensity(double r, double z, double t); //I also define this one.
    };
```

Now that efield is defined (the version that accepts `double r, double z, double t`), I was hoping that my templated version of efield would work by allowing me to call:

```
GaussianBeam gauss = GaussianBeam();
const int Nx = 3;
const int Ny = 2;
    
//creates the "meshgrid"
Eigen::Matrix<double, Ny, Nx> X = Eigen::RowVectorXd::LinSpaced(Nx, -5e-4,5e-4).replicate(Ny,1);
Eigen::Matrix<double, Ny, Nx> Y = Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(Ny, -5e-3, 5e-3).replicate(1, Nx);

    
//calculates the field:
//I would have expected the code to call the parent version of efield since it's the only that matched the signature of the arguments. Yet, I feel like it's trying to call the one that uses doubles that was defined in the class GaussianBeam.
gauss.efield<Nx, Ny>(X, Y, 0);
```

But this last line just says `Invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)` which I do not understand very well since I thought GaussianBeam would inherit the templated version of efield and I would be able to call it from the instance of GaussianBeam.

Why is this happening? What am I misunderstanding about inheritance? Thank you.

Comment: What's `gauss`? This name is never declared in the code shown.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my question. It is fixed now. ``gauss`` is an instance of GaussianBeam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line somewhere in `GaussianBeam`:

```
using CylindricalWave::efield;
```

Otherwise, `efield` member in `GaussianBeam` hides all members named `efield` in the base class. And since `GaussianBeam::efield` is not a template, the compiler assumes that the angle bracket in `gauss.efield<Nx, Ny>(X, Y, 0)` is the less-than operator.